# Making user input a command in IPython

Tags: string, input, command, ipython

I'm fairly new to python, and this question might be fairly specific to the situation. I'm using IPython to create graphs of physics simulations.

The problem I'm running into is when I try and create a program that avoids having to retype the same code over and over. I'm trying to get a user input to execute a command in IPython without having to type everything out yourself.

For example, there is a program I am using called pynbody.what I am trying to do is get it so when I open my test program with ipython, it prompts the user for an input of what the user would like to import. However, I have only been able to get it in as a string, which won't execute.

What is the syntax involved in getting a user input, ie
input= raw_input("What would you like to import? ")

to execute as if it were a command you were typing into IPython, ie
import pynbody

It works fine if you create a program, ie test.py, and in it you have import pynbody. Any ideas on getting this to work from a user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but you could try

`imported_module =  __import__(<string>)`
or
`eval('python expression')` see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

for more complicated, look at the 'ast' module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html)

But for a beginner I would avoid going this road of prompting user for package to import, or enter expression by hand with raw_input.

Comment: I was using the import as an example, as what is actually running is much more complex and wouldn't make sense without context. It is the same premise though, and eval('python expression') worked perfectly. Thanks!